# What is the first non-vanishing multipole moment of this configuration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, multipole-expansion

Imagine that you have a triangle where each side has the length $a$ and a charge $q$ sitting at every vertex. Additionally, we have a charge $-3q$ sitting in the center of the triangle. What is the first non-vanishing multipole moment?

I thought that there cannot be a net charge or dipole moment, but I was uncertain about the quadrupole moment?

Comment: Since the quadrupole moment can be represented by a tensor, and this system has three-fold rotational symmetry, and a tensor with threefold rotational symmetry is proportional to the unit tensor, the system must not have a quadrupole moment. Probably the octopole is the first one.

Comment: which is not in perfect correspondence with the answers below.

Comment: Ah I see. I was forgetting to account for the third dimension. I wrongly assumed that since the charge distribution is planar, that there can't be any components to the quadrupole moment except in the 2x2 submatrix that lies in the plane. I'll leave my comment so hopefully other people won't make the same mistake.

Comment: For a group theory approach, ref D3h case in http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/determining-the-lowest-rank-non-vanishing-multipole-moment/8669#8669

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Spherical Multipole Expansion

The first nonvanishing moment is the quadrupole moment. Assuming that you are looking for an exterior multipole expansion, the potential from the charge distribution $\rho$ can be expanded as

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{L=0}^\infty\sum_{m=-L}^LI_{Lm}(\mathbf{r})\langle R_{Lm},\rho\rangle$$
where $I_{Lm},R_{Lm}$ are the real solid irregular and regular harmonics, respectively (alternately, you can use the complex solid harmonics, but since $\rho$ is real, there is no need to), and $\langle,\rangle$ denotes inner product.

From this we obtain the first several moments (in Mathematica):

```
SphericalHarmonicYr[L_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(I*(SphericalHarmonicY[L, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - (-1)^m*
           SphericalHarmonicY[L, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]))/Sqrt[2], 
     m < 0}, {SphericalHarmonicY[L, 0, \[Theta], \[Phi]], 
     m == 0}, {(SphericalHarmonicY[L, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + (-1)^m*
         SphericalHarmonicY[L, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]])/Sqrt[2], m > 0}}];
SolidHarmonicRr[l_, m_, r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  Limit[Sqrt[(4*Pi)/(2*l + 1)]*R^l*
    SphericalHarmonicYr[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], R -> r];
position = {{0, 0, 0}, {a/Sqrt[3], Pi/2, 0}, {a/Sqrt[3], 
    Pi/2, (2*Pi)/3}, {a/Sqrt[3], Pi/2, (4*Pi)/3}};
charge = {-3*q, q, q, q};
Q[L_, m_] := 
  Sum[charge[[i]]*SolidHarmonicRr[L, m, ##] & @@ position[[i]], {i, 
    4}];
QQ = Simplify[Table[Q[L, m], {L, 0, 2}, {m, -L, L}]]
```

> {{0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -((a^2 q)/2), 0, 0}}

This means that the potential due to the configuration can be well-approximated by
$$\begin{array}{||}\hline
V(\mathbf{r})\approx -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{qa^2}{2}I_{2,0}(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{qa^2 (3 \cos (2 \theta )+1)}{32 \pi  r^3 \epsilon _0}\\\hline
\end{array}$$
which numerically agrees with the exact potential to within $\approx20\%$ at a radius of $|\mathbf{r}|=10a$, and agrees to within $\approx1.5\%$ at $|\mathbf{r}|>100a$.

For reference, the regular real solid harmonics are given by
$$R_{Lm}(\mathbf{r})=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2L+1}}r^L\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}(-1)^m\text{Im}\left[Y_L^{|m|}(\theta,\phi)\right]&m<0\\
Y_L^0(\theta,\phi)&m=0\\
\sqrt{2}(-1)^m\text{Re}\left[Y_L^{|m|}(\theta,\phi)\right]&m>0
\end{cases}\\
=(-1)^mr^L\sqrt{\frac{(L-|m|)!}{(L+|m|)!}}P_L^{|m|}(\cos(\theta))\times\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\sin(|m|\phi)&m<0\\
1&m=0\\
\sqrt{2}\cos(|m|\phi)&m>0
\end{cases}$$
and the irregular harmonics $I_{Lm}$ are the same, but with $r^L$ replaced by $r^{1-L}$.

### Cartesian Multipole Expansion

As vesofilev answered, the traceless Cartesian quadrupole tensor can be obtained via
$$\mathbf{Q}=\langle3\mathbf{r}\otimes\mathbf{r}-|\mathbf{r}|^2\mathbf{I},\rho\rangle$$
which in Mathematica becomes

```
position = 
  Prepend[Table[
    a/Sqrt[3] {Cos[2 \[Pi] k/3], Sin[2 \[Pi] k/3], 0}, {k, 3}], {0, 0,
     0}];
charge = {-3 q, q, q, q};
f[r_] := 3 r\[TensorProduct]r - (r.r) IdentityMatrix[3];
Q = Sum[charge[[k]] f[position[[k]]], {k, 4}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

$$\mathbf{Q}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{a^2 q}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{a^2 q}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -a^2 q \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

The potential can then be approximated as
$$V(\mathbf{r})\approx \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{r}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{r}}{2|\mathbf{r}|^5}.$$

Comment: sorry, what exactly is now the Quadrupole tensor that you get, it is somewhat hard to see through all this ;-)

Comment: @Lipschitz: Ah, are you looking for the Cartesian multipole expansion or the spherical multipole expansion? My answer was a spherical multipole expansion. If you're looking for the Cartesian quadrupole tensor, vesofilev partially showed how to do it, but just for convenience I appended the Cartesian quadrupole tensor of the triangle to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz: Fixed it, I initially forgot the factor of $1/|\mathbf{r}|^5$ in the denominator.

Comment: how can there be a $q^2$ in the tensor?

Comment: the only way to get a $q$ in there is via the charge density and this should contain only linear $q$'s right?

Comment: @Lipschitz: Right, that was an error in my code, I fixed it. Also, I just realized that the Wikipedia article on quadrupole is missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, which I also fixed in my answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz: Never mind, turns out I was wrong and the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is actually not included by convention, and that it is later inserted into the potential $V$ as a factor of 2 in the denominator, which I edited into the answer.

Comment: could you for example explain how you get the entry (1,1) in your matrix, I still don't see it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14476/discussion-between-dumpsterdoofus-and-lipschitz)

Answer (score 2):

It has a non-zero quadrupole moment. The easiest way to see this (Other then computing it) is to consider the expansion of the potential near a point perpendicular to the plane of the triangle and passing through the centre. If you place the origin of the coordinate system also at the origin then the radius vectors of all charges will be perpendicular to the radius vector of the point that you consider. In general you have:

$\begin{equation}V(\vec R)=\sum\limits_i\frac{q_i}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{1}{\left|\,\vec R -\vec r_i\,\right|}=\frac{\sum_iq_i}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\,R}+\frac{\sum_i q_i \vec r_i .\vec R}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\,R^3}+\frac{\sum_iq_i\left[3(\vec R.\vec r_i)^2\,-\,\vec r_i^2\vec R^2\right]}{8\pi\varepsilon_0\,R^5}+O(R^{-4})\end{equation}$

So you can easily check that in your case $\sum_iq_i=0$ and $\sum_i q_i \vec r_i .\vec R =0$. For the third therm the easiest way to check that it is non zero is to calculate it at a point when $\vec R\perp r_i$ (as I explained in the beginning). Indeed, in this case the third term is simply: $-\frac{\sum_i q_i \vec r_i^2}{8\pi\varepsilon_0\,R^3}\neq 0$ so you do have a quadrupole moment.

I hope that helps.